# ELI5. How to add list of publications to my CV using Overleaf?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cv

I am completely new to LaTeX, and was trying to make my CV in Overleaf. I am unable to figure out how to put my list of publications in my CV.

Any resource that I can look into?

I found some answers use \usepackage{bibentry}, but I am not able to get bibentry in Overleaf.

**EDIT:-**

1. I was using this template from [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cv-for-freshers/jkpwvnrdrxpm).
2. Thanks for helping and posting different resources. I went through them and found my LAME mistake. I did not use \addbibresource{} in my document.

The problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for all the help. :)

Comment: May be just use `cvitem/cventry` and manually typset it? Also, welcome to TeX.SE, it would be nice if you can post a MWE that describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are a myriad of CV templates/CV classes out there. Whether and how you can create a list of publications depends on the template or class you use. It would greatly help us if you could show us **(i)** a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) *and* **(ii)** share a link to the template and class you used.

Comment: If you use Overleaf, have a look at the CV templates: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv Some of them already include .bib-files which you only have to edit to fit to your publications.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies have an introduction into bibliographies (or list of references/publications) with LaTeX. On Overleaf there are https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX, https://de.overleaf.com/blog/532-creating-and-managing-bibliographies-with-bibtex-on-overleaf and https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf

Comment: I faced this problem a week ago while working up [my CV](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpvvvxdbpvwf). Just resorted to `\nocite{p1, p2, ...}` to get the references in a section **Publications** at the end.  [Sorry for the advertisement, but thought an example would be the easiest solution instead reading a lot !]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864. Without any further details and going by your tagging I would say that that question would be a good duplicate.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Found my LAME mistake. The problem is resolved now. :)

Comment: Good. I voted to close as a duplicate of the *how to use `biblatex`* question, since that explains the general workings. Since the question contained no code examples, a more specific answer would probably not help future visitors a lot.